# Sort Report table by totals

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, reporting

I have built a report with a table. It looks very much like the table in the following link (last figure, before "Next Steps").

[Microsoft Tutorial: Adding grouping and totals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx)

I have turnover values for products which are grouped by subcategories and categories and have a total for subcategories and categories. I want to sort the table by turnover (in the example it is "line total"). I can do that for the single product values in a subcategory, but not for the totals. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all people interested: the row groups can be sorted by themselves (in Row Group - Group Properties). As the sort expression, one has just to choose SUM(Fields.LineTotal.Value).